# Como mostrar o esconder tres componentes en Angular

Tags: angular, component

Tengo un menu con tres botones y según el botón al que hago click muestro un componente o otro. Son tres botones por lo tanto no me sirve un boolean con true o false.

Gracias de antemano.

Actualmente el fichero html de menu es:

```
<div class="p-2">menu works!<br>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click) = activarComponente() >Gestión de usuarios</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" (click) = activarComponente()>Gestión de productos</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click) = activarComponente()>Gestión de pedidos</button>

    <div *ngIf="option == 0">
        <gestion-usuarios></gestion-usuarios>
    </div>
      
      <div *ngIf="option == 1">
        <gestion-productos></gestion-productos>
      </div>
      
      <div *ngIf="option == 2">
        <gestion-pedidos></gestion-pedidos>
      </div>

</div>
```

Fichero gestion-productos.component.ts(gestion pedidos y usuarios es igual pero cambiando el valor de option):

```
   import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'gestion-productos',
     templateUrl: './gestion-productos.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./gestion-productos.component.css']
  })
 export class GestionProductosComponent implements OnInit {

  opcion:number =1;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

menu.component.ts:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';



@Component({
  selector: 'menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})


export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  option:number;
  @Output() opcion:number;

 activarComponente(){
   this.option = this.opcion;
 }


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

¡Muchísimas gracias de antemano!
¡Saludos!

Comment: Debes usar la directiva [`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf).

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con mi código pero no se porque no funciona...

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres activar diferentes vistas de componentes, puedes realizar comprobaciones con `*ngIf` donde al cumplirse la condición hagas una llamada al `selector` del componente que quieres mostrar.

Por ejemplo, creando una variable `opcion` que almacene `0`, `1` o `2` según lo que deseas mostrar:

```js
<div *ngIf="opcion == 0">
  <app-Componente0></app-Componente0>
</div>

<div *ngIf="opcion == 1">
  <app-Componente1></app-Componente1>
</div>

<div *ngIf="opcion == 2">
  <app-Componente2></app-Componente2>
</div>
```

Esto hará que depende lo que elijas ejecutará el componente.

Comment: ¿Y donde le doy valor a la variable opción? Gracias por la respuesta!

Comment: `opcion` podrías declararla en tu typescript como `public opcion` para poder usarla en tu html. Cada vez que pulses el botón le cambias el valor a opcion con la que necesites.

Comment: Acabo de editar y actualizar la pregunta con el codigo segun lo que me has comentado pero sigo sin entender porque no funciona... ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Yo te recomiendo usar ngSwitch

```
<div [ngSwitch]="conditionExpression">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="expression">output</div>
    <div *ngSwitchDefault>output2</div>
</div>
```

Pero lo que más te recomiendo en todo caso sería usar el router-outlet. Es más fácil a mi pensar.